# Can a new bitcoin block generate 0 coins (reward + fees)?

Tags: bitcoin, cryptocurrency

Would a block have a coinbase transaction if all ~21 million coins have already been rewarded and the miner had a block accepted that only included transactions without fees? Say a large mining pool decided to attempt this by collectively finding a hash to a block without fees as an April Fools' joke.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically possible but might not be in action.
Mining pools are incentivizing people to work for them with the money that comes from the transactions fees and block rewards, So won't invest their time and money to make a joke.

> The majority of the Bitcoins correct functioning is about incentivizing people to do the good job